# How can I get Firebase array to arrayList at Kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I working this like two days but I can't figure out. I have orders at firebase and these orders have basket, this basket have array of products. I can get all products at all orders (in one array) but I need to split baskets for each order, because users may have more than one order. I can't find any way to split that product according to orders. I need array of array type I think. (nested arrays). How can I create array of product for each order and add these arrays to one big array?

**For more clear I add my Firebase:**

[image: Database]

And I get all order's products with this code :

```
private fun getGecmisSiparislerFromFirebase() {

    val us = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.toString()  
    val dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").child(us).child("siparisler")
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Yolunda gitmeyen şeyler oldu..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            for (e in snapshot.children){
                var sipId = e.key.toString()

                val getSepetData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").child(us).child("siparisler").child(sipId).child("sepet")
                getSepetData.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Yolunda gitmeyen şeyler oldu..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        for (e in snapshot.children){

                            val getSepetUrun = e.getValue(SepetModel::class.java)
                            siparislerSepetUrunleri.add(getSepetUrun!!)
                        }
                        gecmis_siparis_rec.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }    
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

My data class is :

```
data class SepetModel(var eklenenUrun: String = "", var eklenenFiyat: String = "", var eklenenAdet: String= "")
```

I can get these from firebase but I can't put these in one array:

First order's basket's products:

> I/System.out: [{eklenenAdet=2, eklenenFiyat=5 ₺, eklenenUrun=Gömlek}, {eklenenAdet=1, eklenenFiyat=4 ₺, eklenenUrun=Gömlek ütü}, {eklenenAdet=2, eklenenFiyat=54 ₺, eklenenUrun=Kaban}]

Second order's basket's products:

> I/System.out: [{eklenenAdet=2, eklenenFiyat=5 ₺, eklenenUrun=Gömlek}, {eklenenAdet=1, eklenenFiyat=20.90 ₺, eklenenUrun=Bluz}, {eklenenAdet=1, eklenenFiyat=23.90 ₺, eklenenUrun=Bluz (ipek)}, {eklenenAdet=1, eklenenFiyat=4.90 ₺, eklenenUrun=Bluz ütü}]

Comment: "I can get these from firebase but I can't put these in one array" Why not? What is keeping you from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I change my data class to:

```
data class GecmisSipModel(var alimAdresi: ArrayList<AdresModel> = arrayListOf(), var sepet: ArrayList<SepetModel> = arrayListOf(), var teslimAdresi: ArrayList<AdresModel> = arrayListOf(), var siparisAlimSaati: String = "", var siparisAlimTarihi: String = "", var siparisTeslimSaati: String = "", var siparisTeslimTarihi: String = "")
```

And I change my get data function to get value from firebase:

```
private fun getGecmisSiparislerFromFirebase() {

    val us = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.toString()  // BURASI CURRENT USER UID YI ALMAKTADIR..
    val dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").child(us).child("siparisler")
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Yolunda gitmeyen şeyler oldu..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            for (e in snapshot.children){
                //println(e.value["sepet"].toString())
                //println(e.value.toString())
                //println("BURADA SEPET ++++++++++")
                val dataSip = e.getValue(GecmisSipModel::class.java)
                genelSipArr.add(dataSip!!)


                    }

                })


            }



}
```

And everything working well. Thanks to firebase.